# Compute md5hash of a file in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to compute the mdhash of a file and having trouble in Python 3. This code worked great in Python 2, but now I get a UnicodeDecodeError:

```
  ###################
  #0 Compute md5hash
  ###################
  try:
    with open(fname) as fo:
      md5 = hashlib.md5()
      chunk_sz = md5.block_size * 128
      data = fo.read(chunk_sz)
      while data:
        md5.update(data)
        data = fo.read(chunk_sz)
      md5hash = md5.hexdigest()
  except IOError:
    md5hash = None
```

The error thrown is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 38: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary mode:

```
with open(fname, 'rb') as fo:
```

Python 3 automatically decodes files opened in text mode using the default encoding, which on your system is UTF-8.